# Installing yum on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, yum

I am trying to install `yum` in Ubuntu but have not been able to.

Here is the output that I ran into.

Is it possible to install it to Ubuntu and how would I be able to do it?

```
2021-10-17 17:55:17 status half-installed tree:amd64 1.8.0-1
2021-10-17 17:55:17 status installed tree:amd64 1.8.0-1
2021-10-17 17:55:19 status installed man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
admin1@admin1-VirtualBox:/var/log$ cat dpkg.log  | grep  'removed'
admin1@admin1-VirtualBox:/var/log$ sudo apt-get install yum
[sudo] password for admin1:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package yum
admin1@admin1-VirtualBox:/var/log$
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last still-supported release of Ubuntu to provide `yum` was 18.04; you won’t find it in later releases.

Since 21.04, the replacement `dnf` is available:

```
sudo apt install dnf
```

In both cases you shouldn’t attempt to use these tools to manage your packages. If you really want to manage packages with `yum` or `dnf`, install a distribution which uses them natively (CentOS, Fedora, RHEL, SUSE...).