# Unable to install yum / dnf on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, apt, yum, dnf, setuptools

I tried the following with root user but unable to install yum on my cloud server.

I already read a similar issue here: [Installing yum on Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673762/installing-yum-on-ubuntu)

```
root@localhost:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

tried the following in vain to install yum.

```
1. 

    root@localhost:~# up2date
    up2date: command not found

2. 

    apt-get update
    apt-get install yum*

3. 

    apt-get install rpm -y
    apt-get install yum*

4. 

    apt update -y
    apt install -y yum-utils
```

Here is the error:

```
root@localhost:~# yum
Command 'yum' not found, did you mean:

  command 'uum' from deb freewnn-jserver (1.1.1~a021+cvs20130302-7build1)
  command 'zum' from deb perforate (1.2-5.1)
  command 'num' from deb quickcal (2.4-1)
  command 'sum' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)

Try: apt install <deb name>
```

Error:

```
root@localhost:~# apt-get install yum -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package yum
```

I cant even get `dnf` installed nor do I know how to. I have a standard script that uses yum so getting yum to work would be great.

```
root@localhost:~# apt-get install dnf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dnf

root@localhost:~# apt install dnf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dnf
```

Comment: Please read the answer you linked again: `yum` was available until 18.04, `dnf` is available since 21.04 so it's simply not possible to install either of those (from official Ubuntu repositories) on 20.04.

Comment: if it doesn't allow using `yum` or `dnf` then what is the best solution to get the current script to work that has many `yum` commands?

Comment: If you have a script with many `yum` commands, and those commands are meant to install packages from `yum` repositories, the script is likely not meant to be run in Ubuntu.  You may need to run the script in an operating system it was meant for.

Comment: ... or simply install the needed packages with `apt` instead of with `yum` (taking care to change the package names appropriately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `yum` is not available on Ubuntu 20.04, so it is better to use `apt` or `apt-get` but in some cases (like following an example or instruction) you need to use the `yum` repository.
In this case, the only way that I found is use of `aptitude`. You can install it simply by `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

if apt-get could not find it, update it and try again. Then you can use the GUI of `aptitude` by direct execution in terminal (`sudo aptitude`) or use the command line to install your package from `yum` repository (in my case I installed `fuse`):

```
sudo aptitude install fuse
```

good luck

Answer (score 3):

`yum` is only available for [Ubuntu Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/yum) from universe repository, it depends on 2.7 =< python <<2.8.